# How to programmatically (C/C++) verify if X11 forwarding is enabled?

Tags: c++, user-interface, ssh, x11-forwarding

The application is run remotely on target hardware. User can choose to enable visual debug output (using command line switches) in that case a ssh's X11 forwarding is used to view it.

The problem starts if user forgets to establish the connection before running the application like this: `ssh -YC remote.host`. The application will crash.

I would like to detect this situation beforehand and print proper message while starting the application.
Is it possible to do it in C/C++? In the worst case I can execute some shell commands in the background.

Comment: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'" - Sounds like there's a convenient exception there that you could `catch` and then print your nice error message before shutting down..

Comment: @JesperJuhl exactly that did happen. the very next line prints the OpenCV formatted error. I've removed the C++ tag because this doesn't require the attention of C++ specialists but OpenCV/GTK/X specialists.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Please read the topic of the post: "How to programmatically (C/C++) verify if X11 forwarding is enabled?". No imagine I do not use OpenCV but plain Qt/GTK whatever. I dont want to rely on OpenCV. I want to check if forwarding is enabled.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Please put the C++ tag back. OpenCV is not the case. Please read the topic carefully. I'm using OpenCV - just describing what I'm doing that is all. I want to "programmatically (C/C++) verify if X11 forwarding is enabled". Any graphical application will fail to start I there is no X11 forwarding enabled - that is what I want to detect beforehand.

Comment: Have you tried calling `XOpenDisplay(nullptr)` ?  Return value is null if there's no X11 display found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XOpenDisplay [man page](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XOpenDisplay.3.html)

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

bool displayIsValid()
{
    char* disp = getenv("DISPLAY");
    if ( disp==nullptr ) return false;
    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(disp);  
    if ( dpy==nullptr ) return false;
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    if ( displayIsValid() ) {
        std::cout << "Display is valid" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an X11 display (real or forwarded by ssh), you have a `DISPLAY` environment variable. Otherwise it should not be present.

The least invasive check is probably:

```
if (!getenv("DISPLAY")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "missing X11 display, have you forgotten something?\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

This should trigger just fine if someone forgets X forwarding in ssh.

Comment: Maybe complement with this to check if DISPLAY is valid: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57500/how-to-check-if-display-is-valid